# Select table value based on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery and need some help.

I would like jquery to select a value inside the Quantities table cell, depending on whether or not a radio button within the table row has been selected.

you can see a screenshot of the table [here](http://oi43.tinypic.com/1247v5t.jpg).

The table name is `tblOfferings`; the radio button name is `rdbOfferings`; the td Offerings name is `offerQuant`.

my attempt so far

```
Quantities = jQuery("td>span:contains('offerQuant')").closest("input[name='rdbOffering']:checked").find('offerQuant').val();
```

help?

Comment: *Which* value do you need JQuery to select within the table?  The logic of selection is basically the entirety of your question, but it's the part that you glossed over.  More importantly, why is your current attempt not working - in which cases does it fail, and what does it (erroneously) return in those cases?

Comment: hmm not sure what you mean, I thought I explained it clearly but i guess not :p I want the value inside the quantities column to get selected. If you look at the screenshot, 200, 400, 600, etc.. depending on whether the radio button has been selected in that row

Comment: well it is hard to tell what's going wrong but undefined is being returned. I tried to view the jquery step by step with chrome but that is almost impossible...

Comment: Maybe you could recreate an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
quantity = $('input[name="rdbOffering"]:checked').parents('tr').find('td.offerQuant').text();
```

i hope that's what you mean

check this http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/Ycm7L/

Comment: interesting thanks for the link! I tried your code on my page but it only returns Quantity = ""

Comment: is there any radiobutton selected when you see the result?

Comment: ya the radio button in the first row is checked as default

Comment: please pay attention to the using of ' (single quote) and " (double quote) order in your selector. compare how you write that with the sample of mine..